# object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The existing object is in the Unchanged state

Tags: c#

I am trying to udpate entries in the DB with the following code

```
public static object SetLateBatchInfo(bool chkEnable, int numThreshold, int numRepeatDays)
        {
            string returnstring = "true";
            try
            {
                using (var dataContext = new SOSEntities())
                {
                    var olateBatchInfo = dataContext.CTRL_OPTION.Where(x => x.OPTION_NAME.Contains("LATE")).FirstOrDefault();
                    
                    if (olateBatchInfo == null)
                    {
                        olateBatchInfo = new CTRL_OPTION();
                    }
                    dataContext.AddToCTRL_OPTION(olateBatchInfo);
                    //LATE_BATCH_EMAILS_ACTIVE
                    //LATE_BATCH_THRESHOLD_DAYS
                    //LATE_BATCH_REPEAT_DAYS

                    dataContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                returnstring = e.Message;
            }
            return returnstring;
        }
```

I am struggling to get the info updated as I get the above mentioned error

**An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The existing object is in the Unchanged state**

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: My guess, put the call to AddToCTRL_OPTION() inside the if. Changes to the object in variable olateBatchInfo are tracked by EF and saved with the call to SaveChanges().